# PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied when trying create VideoFileClip object for video

Tags: python, windows, ffmpeg, moviepy

Im using python 3.6 and this is a module from my project -

```
import os
import time

from moviepy.video.io.VideoFileClip import VideoFileClip

def add_audio_to_file(original_video, dest_video):
    suffix = original_video.split(".")[-1]
    directory_path = os.path.dirname(dest_video)
    temp_name = os.path.join(directory_path, "temp_vid_{}.{}".format(time.time(), suffix))
    os.rename(dest_video, temp_name)

    os.chmod(original_video, 777)

    orig_videoclip = VideoFileClip(original_video)
    audioclip = orig_videoclip.audio
    redorded_videoclip = VideoFileClip(temp_name)
    with_audio_clip = redorded_videoclip.set_audio(audioclip)
    with_audio_clip.write_videofile(dest_video, progress_bar=False, threads=6, verbose=False)
    os.remove(temp_name)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Borat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Borat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\MOT_Server\olympus-skeleton\core\step\step_action\utils\async_queue_reader.py", line 56, in _start_reading_from_queue
    self._new_objects_in_queue_function(queue_objects)
  File "C:\MOT_Server\olympus-skeleton\core\step\step_action\handler\async_handler.py", line 29, in _listener_to_handler_queue_messages_handler
    messages = self._handle_function(messages)
  File "C:\MOT_Server\olympus-skeleton\core\step\step.py", line 261, in process
    processed_messages = handler(curr_messages)
  File "C:\MOT_Server\olympus-skeleton\core\step\step.py", line 239, in _handle_message
    final_messages = self._process(messages_to_process) or []
  File "C:\MOT_Server\olympus-skeleton\components\steps\output_step\output_step.py", line 40, in _process
    publisher.publish(messages)
  File "C:\MOT_Server\olympus-skeleton\core\publisher\publisher.py", line 28, in publish
    self._publish(messages)
  File "C:\MOT_Server\olympus-skeleton\components\publishers\filesystem_cleaner_publisher\filesystem_cleaner_publisher.py", line 32, in _publish
    files_to_delete = self._serializer.serialize(message)
  File "C:\MOT_Server\olympus-skeleton\components\serializers\mot_serializers\job_completed_verifier_serializer.py", line 182, in serialize
    self._add_audio_to_vid(original_video, dest_video)
  File "C:\MOT_Server\olympus-skeleton\components\serializers\mot_serializers\job_completed_verifier_serializer.py", line 201, in _add_audio_to_vid
    add_audio_to_file(original_video, dest_video)
  File "C:\MOT_Server\olympus-skeleton\utils\recorder_utils\audio_utils.py", line 17, in add_audio_to_file
    orig_videoclip = VideoFileClip(original_video)
  File "C:\Users\Borat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\VideoFileClip.py", line 91, in __init__
    fps_source=fps_source)
  File "C:\Users\Borat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\ffmpeg_reader.py", line 33, in __init__
    fps_source)
  File "C:\Users\Borat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\ffmpeg_reader.py", line 259, in ffmpeg_parse_infos
    proc.terminate()
  File "C:\Users\Borat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\gevent\subprocess.py", line 982, in terminate
    TerminateProcess(self._handle, 1)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
```

I checked the permissions and everything seems ok. In addition, i tried to change the permissions using `os.chmod(original_video, 777)`, but still without any success.

Comment: try `os.chmod(original_video, 0o777)`, you need octal. But that is not the issue.

Comment: Are you running the program out of an IDE or the terminal/command prompt?  If you are running it outside of the IDE in newer versions of windows, you have to right click and open your command prompt/powershell/anaconda prompt/whatever as administrator or you will get access denied [5] errors.  If you are running it inside the IDE, that's a little weirder but you may try opening the IDE as administrator in that case.  The way permissions are handled on windows sucks.

Comment: Ran the script out of an IDE and cmd with administrator privileges..